# Deactivate pyenv in current shell

Tags: python, pyenv

My `.bashrc` has this:

```
enable-pyenv () {
    # Load pyenv automatically by adding
    # the following to your profile:

    export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
    eval "$(pyenv init -)"
    eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
}

enable-pyenv
```

Which enables pyenv. In some situations, I want to (temporarily) disable pyenv. How can I do this?

Comment: Define "temporarily". You want to disable pyenv for a bash session ?

Comment: @Marcs: Yes, indeed, because it conflicts with a good old virtualenv

Comment: I would simply comment out like this `#enable-pyenv` and open a new bash session. If it is acceptable to open a new bash session for you, just remember that .bashrc is read only when a bash is initialized.

Comment: @Marcs: not even sure that would apply in my case since I open shells inside a tmux session which is run in a bash session where pyenv was already enabled, so very probably any shell within tmux has pyenv enabled, even if I edit the .bashrc. I can open a brand new terminal, but since this is gonna bite me more than once, I would like to have a way of cleanly disabling (and re-enabling) pyenv in my current shell.

Comment: I checked out a little and to do what you want directly inside a shell you should reverse the pyenv init - shell function, which changes a bunch of stuff and looks like is piping your commands through pydev. Try to launch `pyenv init -` in a shell and you'll see the shell code relative to your bash. So i would create a script with the reverse function to call it when you want to turnoff pydev. I'm speaking theoretically, I don't know how pydev works.

Comment: I’ve taken something of an opposite approach: I wrote a shell function `pyinit()` which initialises `pyenv`, prepends its shim directory to the `$PATH` and does some further initialisation.  In other words, `pyenv` is not active _until I want it to be_.  If I have already activated `pyenv` in my current shell and I need to get rid of it, I just open a new shell — cheap and easy on modern hardware.

Comment: @wjv can you share your shell function? I'm assuming you don't mean a bash script?

Comment: @mcExchange My function, when boiled down to the bare basics, wasn't that different from the one posted in the question — I just didn't then *also call it* after defining it in my shell startup. The point I was making in my comment was that instead of always activating pyenv and having a way to disable it, one could rather enable it when needed and discard the shell afterwards. Personally I don't use pyenv much anymore, but I use a streamlined version of the same idea for other tools.

Comment: You may want: `pyenv shell --unset` - From `pyevn shell --help`:

> When `-` is passed instead of the version string, the previously set
version will be restored. With `--unset`, the `PYENV_VERSION`
environment variable gets unset, restoring the environment to the
state before the first `pyenv shell` call.

Answer (score 74):

If you want to use the python version from your system temporarily (until you close your current shell):

```
pyenv shell system
```

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md#pyenv-shell

If you want by default your system's python

```
pyenv global system
```

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md#pyenv-global

Suppose your shell is currently in the 'src' folder and you want src and all its subfolders to use by default a specific version of python installed with pyenv, named for instance dev311:

```
pyenv local dev311
```

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md#pyenv-local

Edited to take into account the comments

Comment: You probably want `pyenv shell system` otherwise you'll affect only shells in that current directory (or below).

Comment: continuation on above comment from @davidA, be careful moving to other projects after using the `pyenv shell system`. It will take precedence over the .python-version file created by `pyenv local` command. Don't forget to unset shell using `pyenv shell --unset` or close the shell when working on other projects.

Answer (score 33):

To deactivate from current shell environment, try:

```bash
pyenv shell --unset
```

Comment: This has no effect at all.

Comment: @sorin shell versions > local versions > global versions. Check `pyenv versions` to see which Python version is currently active.

Comment: This is to back out from a shell usage (temp use) `pyenv shell 3.11.5` change when your pyenv local is 3.10.4

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure that this will get rid of all traces of pyenv, but editing your `$PATH` environment variable to get rid of the pyenv- or shim-containing paths seems to deactivate pyenv. Eg,

```
export PATH=`echo $PATH | python -c "import sys, re; print(':'.join(x for x in sys.stdin.read().strip().split(':') if not 'pyenv' in x))"`
```

If you want to be able to re-enable it, just store your previous `$PATH` so you can restore it later.

Answer (score 7):

Try playing around with some variants of:

`env -i bash`

`env -i bash -l`

`env -i bash --norc`

`env -i bash --norc --noprofile`

This does not come without side effects as `env -i` nukes your whole session and thus afterwards a lot of convenience like `$HOME` is gone with the bathwater, but so is `pyenv`.

Answer (score 3):

For me, what worked ultimately was the brute force method of removing all `pyenv` paths from the `$PATH` variable:

```
PATH=`echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | sed '/pyenv/d' | tr '\n' ':' | sed -r 's/:$/\n/'`
```

I wish `pyenv` offered a better way by itself.

Answer (score 3):

I use this but not sure if it is a good way

```
bash
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the posted answers worked for me but the following did:

```
$ echo "" > /home/myusername/.pyenv/version
```

Comment: This does not work, it only removes the prompt, it still points to the same shim, you also need to remove it from path and unset all the PYENV_* env-variables

Answer (score 1):

I have macOS Monterey, v12.0.1.
Prophet was successfully installed using python 3.8.
It did NOT work with 3.9 versions.
I use pyenv to create virtual env. That is what I did:

`pip3 install virtualenv`

`pip3 install virtualenvwrapper`

`brew install pyenv-virtualenv`

You need these commands to have virtual env running under pyenv.
Next, install python

`pyenv install 3.8.10`

Create env called 'prophet':

`pyenv virtualenv 3.8.10 prophet`

Activate it in your working directory:

`pyenv local prophet`

Install 2 packages:

`pip install pystan==2.19.1.1`

`pip install prophet`

It worked fine for me!

Comment: Hi Dmitry, did you accidentally paste this answer to the wrong site? Someone (probably you) also pasted it [here](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/2002#issuecomment-1058543235) where it is much more on-topic. It'll probably be deleted here. Cheers! --Sietse

Answer (score 1):

```
pyenv shell system
```

[You can use the pyenv shell command to set this environment variable in your current shell session.](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#choosing-the-python-version)

Answer (score 0):

that worked for me, to deactivate pyenv:

```
#show shell variables (set) and environment/exported variables (env)
{ set; env; } | egrep -i pyenv
#unset variables and functions:
unset PYENV_ROOT PYENV_SHELL _pyenv pyenv
#remove from PATH:
PATH=$(echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | egrep -v pyenv | paste -sd:)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case getting back to using my conda environment instead of pyenv temporarily, the simplest method was to re-set the PATH veriable in the current shell:

1. Check current PATH

```
echo $PATH
/Users/fsk/.pyenv/shims:/Users/fsk/miniconda3/envs/polar/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/local/bin:...
```

2. Remove pyenv part

```
export PATH="/Users/fsk/miniconda3/envs/polar/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/local/bin"
```

Answer (score -4):

Try `pyenv deactivate`, to manually deactivate the virtual env.

Doc here: https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough: I want to disable `pyenv` completely (for a bash session), because it conflicts with a normal virtualenv (outside the control of pyenv). I do not want to disable a specific virtualenv environment controlled by pyenv, but **completely** disable pyenv (for a bash session)

Comment: Using another custom .bashrc could be a solution then.

Comment: sure, and moving to another computer :) But there must be a way to disable pyenv in the current shell session?

Comment: Just `cp` your `.bachrc` to i.e. `.bashrc_clean`  then `source .bashrc_clean`, on the session you want is enough :)

Comment: Nonono, the current shell has already pyenv enabled, commenting it out and resourcing will not disable it.