# How do you disable Pyenv?

Tags: pyenv

I do not want to uninstall `pyenv` because I might want to use it later.  I've seen a lot of solutions over here [Deactivate pyenv in current shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348806/deactivate-pyenv-in-current-shell)
but none of them work.  I commented out the commands on my `.bashrc` files like so:

```
#export PATH="/Users/kylefoley/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
#eval "$(pyenv init -)"
#eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

And I put the following line on my `.bash_profile`:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
```

I then restarted my Terminal and when I enter `which python` it still outputs:

```
/Users/kylefoley/.pyenv/shims/python
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked in terminal:

```
mv .pyenv pyenv
```