# How to deactivate pyenv?

Tags: python, miniconda, pyenv

So I setup a pyenv environment with python 3.7. Now I want to use a miniforge environment. However even if I activate the miniforge environment it seems the pyenv shell overwrites it because it runs the code with the 3.7 python executable. I have tried `pyenv deactivate` but it doesn't work (it says it doesn't exist). How would I fix this?

Comment: It turns out I just had to change my interpreter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deactivate pyenv in current shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348806/deactivate-pyenv-in-current-shell)

Answer (score 0):

have your tried simple ** deactivate **