# Unable to deactivate pyenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv

I am presently in the virtualenv `py37`:

```
(py37) 00:31:04/Applications $
```

I have tried

`deactivate`

`source deactivate`

`[source] deactivate py37`

None of these result in my "escaping" from the `py37` virtualenv.  Trying `exit` kills the entire `bash` session.    What must I do to escape from Alcatraz (but without blowing the entire island up ) ?

Note I have tried the various suggestions at [deactivate pyenv in current shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348806/deactivate-pyenv-in-current-shell)  None of the ones *not having side-effects* worked.

Comment: See related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348806/deactivate-pyenv-in-current-shell

Comment: @Mihai8 I'll add that link but none of the suggestions worked